# TextFormField loses value

Tags: flutter

I have a PageView having 4 children/pages/steps.
On the first page I have a TextFormField. The user is obligated to provide a value.
When following exactly these steps, wrongly it will result in an error message for the user 'Please provide a name':

1. page is created
2. type a value into the TextFormField
3. Tap 'Done' on the soft keyboard
4. Tap the Next-button to go to page 2 of the PageView
5. Tap the Back-button to go to page 1 of the PageView
6. Tap the Next-button to go to page 2 of the PageView: now 'Please provide a name' is shown to the user. The typed name is still visible on the page, but its value in its validator is empty.

Deviation from the above will not cause the error message. Relevant code:

```
class CreateWishlist extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CreateWishlistState createState() => _CreateWishlistState();
}

class _CreateWishlistState extends State<CreateWishlist> {
  ...
  final myTitleController = TextEditingController();
  final _form1 = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

```
          Form(
            key: _form1,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Name'),
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _createWishlistData['title'] = value.trim();
                  },
                  controller: myTitleController,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.trim().isEmpty) return 'Please provide a name';
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

```
  next(int pageIndex) {
    if (pageIndex == 0) {
      FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
      if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
        currentFocus.unfocus();
      }
      if (!_form1.currentState.validate()) {
        return;
      }
      _form1.currentState.save();
    }
    controller.animateToPage(pageIndex + 1,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.ease);
  }
```

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56159

Comment: flutter saves memory by removing the widgets not drawn on the screen. Wrap your widget with https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/KeepAlive-class.html or https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html for custom widget.

Answer (score 0):

I tried as described in the comments above, but still the same. Eventually I managed to avoid the problem by overwriting the value on the validator and on onSaved by the controller-value.

```
                TextFormField(
                  style: formFieldTextStyle,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Name'),
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    value = myTitleController.text;
                    _createWishlistData['title'] = value.trim();
                  },
                  controller: myTitleController,
                  validator: (value) {
                    value = myTitleController.text;
                    if (value.trim().isEmpty) return 'Please provide a name';
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
```